# Groovy DSL for Extended choice parameter plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm converting my Jenkins job configurations into code using groovy DSL. Am able to convert all the code except extended choice parameter plugin configuration.

I've a groovy script which does some API calls and get the values and return as choice to the defied parameter in the job. I've tested it and working fine. But, when I tried to automate/convert the same into Groovy DSL am not getting enough support from the plugin rather I haven't find any document which helps me with this situation.

kindly help.

Answer (score 3):

I went through the same process a couple of months ago. I found this article tremendously useful - http://www.devexp.eu/2014/10/26/use-unsupported-jenkins-plugins-with-jenkins-dsl.

Here's a sample code snippet:

```
configure {
    project->
        project / 'properties' << 'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty' {
        parameterDefinitions {
            'com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended__choice__parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition' {
                name 'TARGET_ENVS'
                quoteValue 'false'
                saveJSONParameterToFile 'false'
                visibleItemCount '15'
                type 'PT_CHECKBOX'
                value "${deployTargets}"
                multiSelectDelimiter ','
                projectName "${jobName}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The article suggests appending the 'configure' code block at the end of your DSL job definition, however that didn't work for me. I ended up putting the code block at the start of the definition.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Job DSL plugins allows you to add XML configuration to jobs `config.xml` files. You have to use `configure` closure and next specify whatever you want. For example I have such configuration:

```
<hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
  <parameterDefinitions>
    <com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended__choice__parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition plugin="extended-choice-parameter@0.76">
      <name>PRODUCT_REPO_URL</name>
      <description>ssh URL of the product repository</description>
      <quoteValue>false</quoteValue>
      <saveJSONParameterToFile>false</saveJSONParameterToFile>
      <visibleItemCount>10</visibleItemCount>
      <type>PT_SINGLE_SELECT</type>
      <groovyScript>import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Jenkins.get().globalNodeProperties.get(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class).envVars.get(&apos;PRODUCT_REPOSITORIES&apos;)</groovyScript>
      <bindings></bindings>
      <groovyClasspath></groovyClasspath>
      <defaultGroovyScript>import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Jenkins.get().globalNodeProperties.get(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class).envVars.get(&apos;PRODUCT_REPOSITORY_DEFAULT&apos;)</defaultGroovyScript>
      <defaultBindings></defaultBindings>
      <defaultGroovyClasspath></defaultGroovyClasspath>
      <multiSelectDelimiter>,</multiSelectDelimiter>
      <projectName>try-to-upgrade-dependencies</projectName>
    </com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended__choice__parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition>
  </parameterDefinitions>
</hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
```

Now I can generate it by adding the following code:

```
configure {
    project -> project / 'properties' << 'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty' {
        parameterDefinitions {
            'com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended__choice__parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition'(plugin: 'extended-choice-parameter@0.76') {
                delegate.name('PRODUCT_REPO_URL')
                delegate.description('ssh URL of the product repository')
                delegate.quoteValue(false)
                delegate.saveJSONParameterToFile(false)
                delegate.visibleItemCount(10)
                delegate.type('PT_SINGLE_SELECT')
                delegate.groovyScript("""import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Jenkins.get().globalNodeProperties.get(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class).envVars.get('PRODUCT_REPOSITORIES')""")
                delegate.defaultGroovyScript("""import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Jenkins.get().globalNodeProperties.get(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class).envVars.get('PRODUCT_REPOSITORY_DEFAULT')""")
                delegate.multiSelectDelimiter(',')
                delegate.projectName('try-to-upgrade-dependencies')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The final result:

```
<hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
    <parameterDefinitions>
        <com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended__choice__parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition plugin="extended-choice-parameter@0.76">
            <name>PRODUCT_REPO_URL</name>
            <description>ssh URL of the product repository</description>
            <quoteValue>false</quoteValue>
            <saveJSONParameterToFile>false</saveJSONParameterToFile>
            <visibleItemCount>10</visibleItemCount>
            <type>PT_SINGLE_SELECT</type>
            <groovyScript>import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Jenkins.get().globalNodeProperties.get(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class).envVars.get('PRODUCT_REPOSITORIES')</groovyScript>
            <defaultGroovyScript>import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Jenkins.get().globalNodeProperties.get(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class).envVars.get('PRODUCT_REPOSITORY_DEFAULT')</defaultGroovyScript>
            <multiSelectDelimiter>,</multiSelectDelimiter>
            <projectName>try-to-upgrade-dependencies</projectName>
        </com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended__choice__parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition>
    </parameterDefinitions>
</hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
```